# React Form hook - getting "required field" error message despite input being entered

Tags: validation, react-hook-form

I just started building a form using react form hook. Just started with single input called name and when I submit the form I get the error message.

I tried to follow these instructions:
https://react-hook-form.com/get-started

```
//I have tried with this but I get unexpected token error:
 <input {...register('name', { required: true })} />
```

---

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'



const NewUserForm = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit,  formState: { errors } } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = data => console.log(data)


    return (

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" ref={register('name', {required: true})} />
        {errors.name && <span> This field is required</span>} 
     <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" ref={register('email', {required: true})} />
        {errors.email && <span> This field is required</span>} 
        <input type="submit" />            
      </form>
    )
}

export default NewUserForm
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried optional chaining the errors?

`errors?.email?.message`

https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#ErrorMessages

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just use the spread operator before the register function, and remove the ref attribute, just like the following:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" {...register('name', {required: true})} />
```

*Also, it is recommended to remove the name attribute, because it may overwrite the field name in the register function*

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
   <input 
     type="text" 
     {...register("name", { required: true})} />;
    {
      errors.name && <p>Name is required</p>;
    }
```

If you want to learn more about error messages in React hook form you can check out this article:
https://www.operationdev.com/blog/how-to-display-error-messages-in-react-hook-form/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
        type='text'
        placeholder="Enter Name"
        {...register("username", {
                required: 'Username is required'
         })}
 />
 <small>{errors?.username?.message}</small>
```

Try this! Should work.

Answer (score 0):

you should not add name field in the input you are registering with react hook form try removing name property.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).